# Mechanize authentication error 401 when saving file to a shared drive

Tags: ruby, mechanize, ntlm

I am connected to a shared SMB volume. Using Mechanize in a Ruby script, I am trying to download several files from a proprietary asset manager, and save them directly to the shared drive, i.e.:

```
agent = Mechanize.new
agent.add_auth("http://website.com", username, password)
agent.get(URL).save("/Volumes/shared_folder/file.pdf")
```

This works successfully for a few iterations/files, and then eventually throws a 401 error each time:

```
/Users/m/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mechanize-2.7.6/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb:775:in `response_authenticate': 401 => Net::HTTPUnauthorized for [url] -- NTLM authentication failed -- available realms:  (Mechanize::UnauthorizedError)
    from /Users/m/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mechanize-2.7.6/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb:323:in `fetch'
    from /Users/m/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mechanize-2.7.6/lib/mechanize.rb:464:in `get'
```

However, if I change it so that the files are saved locally, in the same working folder that I am running my Ruby script, I get no errors at all.

The credentials for the website and for the shared drive are not the same, so I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Is there any way around this that does not involve saving files directly to my computer?

**Edit:**

If I add a rescue clause like this, the script is able to finish its execution:

```
rescue Mechanize::UnauthorizedError => e
agent = Mechanize.new
agent.add_auth("http://website.com", username, password)
retry
```

Although this works, it is triggered every 1-3 iterations, and it overall just feels like a clunky solution.

I also tried setting the timeout with `agent.read_timeout`, but I don't necessarily know how long each iteration would actually take, so I don't have a concrete value to define.

Comment: If it stops after a couple of iterations, then there might be a rate limit.

Comment: Can you clarify what is triggering the error? It looks like it's your call to `get(URL)` that is triggering it, not the call to `.save`. A complete stack trace would be helpful.

Comment: @anothermh You're right, it does appear to be the call to `get`. I edited with the rest of the error's stack trace.

Comment: @spickermann As in a rate limit defined by mechanize, or externally?

Comment: It would be a rate limit set by the remote host. Since the problem is with `.get` and not `.save` I suggest you run some tests that skip the `.save` call entirely. (you can access anything you `get` using `agent.history`) Using the exact same URLs and exact same credentials run the script using only `agent.get(URL)` until you can create a reproducible error. 401 is *supposed* to mean *The request requires user authentication* but it can actually mean whatever the remote host wants it to mean. Verify that each request being made includes proper auth, especially the one that fails.

Comment: And please try using something other than a constant for `URL`, e.g., `url`.